# Как привести в соответствие третий модель, если на первых двух название столбца называется Id, а третяя id_slujbi

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Подскажите плз, как привести в соответствие третий модель, если на первых двух название столбца называется Id, а третяя id_slujbi.Поменять id_slujbi на id не могу так как уже на этой базе работает программа на winforms.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

...

public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Spr_slujbi : Entity
{
    [Column("id_slujbi")]
    public new int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```